# How to start listview item from bottom to top?

Tags: android

Hello sir I want to my list view from bottom like bellow image..
[image]

I want to show it from bottom to top..
Here I use list view xml code ...

```
             <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_10"
                android:stackFromBottom="true"
                />
```

How to do it ? please help me

Comment: you can use the a list.reverse method, in java Collections.reverse(myList)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stackFromBottom` attribute along with auto scroll to bottom whenever the view is updated.

Add the following to your ListView.

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
```